# How to merge two time series data in R?

Tags: r, date, merge, time-series

I have two time series data. One including drug name, start date of usage, Stop date of usage, and dose of drug and second data including visit date and score,

```
data1<- data.frame("Drug Name" = c("Drug1","Drug1","Drug2","Drug1","Drug3","Drug2",
                                   "Drug4","Drug5","Drug1"), 
                   "Start Date" = c("7/1/2016","1/1/2016", "8/6/2015","2/1/2015","6/14/2017",
                                    "6/21/2017","1/24/2018","7/30/2018","7/30/2018"),
                   "Stop Date "=c("1/14/2017","1/14/2017", "1/14/2017","1/14/2017"
                                  ,"1/24/2018","6/29/2018","6/29/2018","Ongoing","Ongoing"),
                   "Dose"=c(12,20,32,3,5,6,6,8,9))
data2<-data.frame("visitdate"=c("8/24/2016","8/24/2016", "10/19/2016","12/7/2016","12/21/2016",
                                "3/22/2017","5/10/2017", "6/14/2017", "7/12/2017","9/27/2017", 
                                "11/29/2017", "1/24/2018","3/21/2018","5/30/2018","8/15/2018",
                                "10/3/2018", "11/28/2018"),
                  "Score"=c(1,2,3,34,6,7,9,5,6,8,5,5,7,9,1,2,5))
```

I would like to merge these two data in a way that for example on visit date `8/24/2016` tells me how many drugs the patient has taken with its dose plus the clinical score.

Comment: Do you want a time series or a data frame (as a data structure)? Because in your question you have two data frames.

Comment: There is no column with patient, this is probably needed.

Comment: I want a dataframe like the picture I uploaded. These two data belong to one patient, who had multiple visits. In my main dataset, there are 100 of observations.

Comment: and how do you get a score of 5??

Comment: Score is a column in the second data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be some pre-processing of data to consider early on.

First, your example above has column names with spaces, would be nice to avoid. I edited and removed spaces for this example.

In addition, you have "Ongoing" as a date. Would recommend converting to dates using `as.Date`. However, after converting those with "Ongoing" will be included as `NA`. These can be set to `Inf` (infinity) which will work.

For example:

```
data1$StartDate <- as.Date(data1$StartDate, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
data1$StopDate <- as.Date(data1$StopDate, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
data2$VisitDate <- as.Date(data2$VisitDate, format = "%m/%d/%Y")

data1$StopDate[8:9] <- Inf
```

There are a number of other ways to address this, depending on your source of data.

After that, you can use `tidyverse` and `fuzzyjoin` to do the following. Using `fuzzy_left_join` you can join your two data frames together, where only the dates within the date range are included.

You might consider leaving the results in long form. However, if you want the wide format, you can use `pivot_wider`. The final `select` puts the columns in order numerically as in your example.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fuzzyjoin)

fuzzy_left_join(data2,
                data1,
                by = c("VisitDate" = "StartDate",
                       "VisitDate" = "StopDate"),
                match_fun = list(`>=`, `<=`)) %>%
  select(-StartDate, -StopDate) %>%
  group_by(VisitDate, Score) %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number(),
         NumDrugs = ifelse(all(is.na(DrugName)) == TRUE, 0, n())) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(VisitDate, Score, NumDrugs), names_from = rn, values_from = c(DrugName, Dose)) %>%
  select(VisitDate, Score, NumDrugs, names(.)[-c(1:3)][order(parse_number(names(.)[-c(1:3)]))])
```

**Output**

```
   VisitDate  Score NumDrugs DrugName_1 Dose_1 DrugName_2 Dose_2 DrugName_3 Dose_3 DrugName_4 Dose_4
   <date>     <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>       <dbl> <chr>       <dbl> <chr>       <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
 1 2016-08-24     1        4 Drug1          12 Drug1          20 Drug2          32 Drug1           3
 2 2016-08-24     2        4 Drug1          12 Drug1          20 Drug2          32 Drug1           3
 3 2016-10-19     3        4 Drug1          12 Drug1          20 Drug2          32 Drug1           3
 4 2016-12-07    34        4 Drug1          12 Drug1          20 Drug2          32 Drug1           3
 5 2016-12-21     6        4 Drug1          12 Drug1          20 Drug2          32 Drug1           3
 6 2017-03-22     7        0 NA             NA NA             NA NA             NA NA             NA
 7 2017-05-10     9        0 NA             NA NA             NA NA             NA NA             NA
 8 2017-06-14     5        1 Drug3           5 NA             NA NA             NA NA             NA
 9 2017-07-12     6        2 Drug3           5 Drug2           6 NA             NA NA             NA
10 2017-09-27     8        2 Drug3           5 Drug2           6 NA             NA NA             NA
11 2017-11-29     5        2 Drug3           5 Drug2           6 NA             NA NA             NA
12 2018-01-24     5        3 Drug3           5 Drug2           6 Drug4           6 NA             NA
13 2018-03-21     7        2 Drug2           6 Drug4           6 NA             NA NA             NA
14 2018-05-30     9        2 Drug2           6 Drug4           6 NA             NA NA             NA
15 2018-08-15     1        2 Drug5           8 Drug1           9 NA             NA NA             NA
16 2018-10-03     2        2 Drug5           8 Drug1           9 NA             NA NA             NA
17 2018-11-28     5        2 Drug5           8 Drug1           9 NA             NA NA             NA
```

**Data**

(Before converting dates)

```
data1 <- structure(list(DrugName = c("Drug1", "Drug1", "Drug2", "Drug1", 
"Drug3", "Drug2", "Drug4", "Drug5", "Drug1"), StartDate = c("7/1/2016", 
"1/1/2016", "8/6/2015", "2/1/2015", "6/14/2017", "6/21/2017", 
"1/24/2018", "7/30/2018", "7/30/2018"), StopDate = c("1/14/2017", 
"1/14/2017", "1/14/2017", "1/14/2017", "1/24/2018", "6/29/2018", 
"6/29/2018", NA, NA), Dose = c(12, 20, 32, 3, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))

data2 <- structure(list(VisitDate = c("8/24/2016", "8/24/2016", "10/19/2016", 
"12/7/2016", "12/21/2016", "3/22/2017", "5/10/2017", "6/14/2017", 
"7/12/2017", "9/27/2017", "11/29/2017", "1/24/2018", "3/21/2018", 
"5/30/2018", "8/15/2018", "10/3/2018", "11/28/2018"), Score = c(1, 
2, 3, 34, 6, 7, 9, 5, 6, 8, 5, 5, 7, 9, 1, 2, 5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-17L))
```